# How to know what a certain "defaults write" command changes?

Tags: defaults

I have seen a few different posts on this site and others containing the command

```
$ defaults write ...
```

What I'm wondering is how do you know what `defaults write` command to use to change what you want to?

Comment: Try typing `man defaults` in the Terminal! :)

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I edited my question :)

Comment: You can use `defaults read` (exact syntax is in man page) to see a subset of possible preferences and what they're set to—but there are many, many other options that aren't listed there. Some defaults write commands were not discovered until people reverse engineered Apple binaries. It's likely that there's a ton of options no one outside of Apple knows about, or ever will know!

Comment: @Wowfunhappy True, but that's awfully ugly and unintuitive. Is there some web site that explains better?